# xamarin grid layout not showing any data

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a Grid inside a ListView and would like to display a 2 column grid inside each listview item.

I don't whant to fix it on a model since I would like to keep it as generic as possible since my backand is providing "dynmaci data structures" (json)

So I tought it would be easyer to do this in the code behind

**XAML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Analytics.Views.AnlDataPage">
</ContentPage>
```

Pretty straight forward since the magic is happening behind the scene.

**CodeBehind**

```
public partial class AnlDataPage : ContentPage
{
    AnlDataModel _model;

    public AnlDataPage(WfDataCollection objectData)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = _model = new AnlDataModel(objectData);
        Populate();
    }

    public void Populate()
    {

        var AnlDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            var grid = new Grid();
            grid.ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection
            {
                new ColumnDefinition {
                    Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
                },
                new ColumnDefinition {
                    Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
                }
            };



            if (_model.Columns != null)
            {
                int i = 0;
                foreach (WfDataColumn column in _model.Columns)
                {
                    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

                    Label columnLabel = new Label {
                        Text = _model.ObjectData.Translations[column.LangKey],
                    };
                    Label valueLabel = new Label
                    {
                        Text = "some value",
                    };
                    grid.Children.Add(columnLabel, 0, i);
                    grid.Children.Add(valueLabel, 1, i);

                    i++;
                }
            }                

            return new ViewCell { View = grid };
        });

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Margin = new Thickness(20),
            Children = {
            new ListView { ItemsSource = _model.Data, ItemTemplate = AnlDataTemplate, Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0) }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The output is that the listview is displayed and the height of rows looks good for the data.

But nothing is displayed in the listItem.

If I omit the `left` and `top` of the `grid.Children.Add(item,left,top)` then the labels are all displayed but are overlapping ofc.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes along the same problem.

Basically. My initial aproach was completely fine. The only problem is that if you have rows that are uneven in height you need to set one [Xamarin.Forms.ListView.HasUnevenRows Property](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.HasUnevenRows/)

Witch is something else as I expected initialy.

```
   Content = new StackLayout
    {
        Margin = new Thickness(20),
        Children = {
            new ListView {
                HasUnevenRows = true,
                ItemsSource = _model.Data,
                ItemTemplate = AnlDataTemplate,
                Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0)
            }
        }
    };
```